# ftp mget don't overwrite

Tags: ftp, sftp

I'm using mget in an ftp script and would like mget to skip getting files that already exist in my local directory. Is there such a way? If so, is there also a way for mget to proceed if the local and remote files are different?

EDIT: Both are excellent answers, I went with the 2nd because it provided an example which I modified to:

```
lftp $HOST -u $USER,$PASSWD -e 'mirror --verbose=3 --only-newer --include "my-extended-regex-expression-of-include-file-patterns" / transfer/'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different `ftp` implementations. I don't know of any `ftp` program that has an `mget` command that checks local files before downloading.

There are many programs that can download files over FTP and that do have what you want.

- [lftp](https://lftp.yar.ru/)

  ```
  lftp ftp.example.com <<EOF
  mirror --only-missing --file=/path/to/*.ext .
  EOF
  ```

  Replace `--only-missing` by `--only-newer` to download only newer files.
- [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/wget.html)

  ```
  wget -nc 'ftp://ftp.example.com/path/to/*.ext'
  ```

  Add the option `-N` to download only newer files.

Alternatively, and this is the best solution to do complex things, mount the remote filesystem and then use normal file manipulation tools. You can mount an FTP directory with [CurlFtpFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/).

```
mkdir mnt
curlftpfs ftp://ftp.example.com/ mnt
rsync -a --ignore-existing mnt/*.ext .   # replace --ignore-existing by -u to download only newer files
fusermount -u mnt
```

Answer (score 3):

`ftp` by itself can't do this (nor do most variations of `sftp`).  That's usually done using a more capable program such as `rsync` or `lftp`.

If you're unable to use `rsync`, there are applications which use `ftp` that can be configured for the first part (existing files), at least.  For example:

- [Mirroring directory hierarchy using FTP protocol](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ftpmirror)

But (having used both that and the related Perl script), `rsync` and `lftp` warrant some study:

- [rsync examples](https://rsync.samba.org/examples.html)
- [Rsync (Remote Sync): 10 Practical Examples of Rsync Command in Linux](http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/)

and

- [Linux / Unix: lftp Command Mirror Files and Directories](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/lftp-mirror-example/)
- [Using LFTP (FTP) to mirror/transfer files from one server to another](https://smyl.es/using-lftp-ftp-to-mirrortransfer-files-from-one-server-to-another/)